# Calculating a product recursively only using addition

Tags: haskell, recursion

I don't know why the following haskell source code for calculating products recursively only using addition doesn't work.

```
mult a b = a + mult a (b-1)
```

I'm always getting a stack overflow error.

Comment: "I'm always getting a stack overflow error." Seems like you've come to the right place to ask.

Answer (score 11):

You'll have to specify a termination condition, otherwise the recursion will run infinitely.

```
mult a 0 = 0
mult a b = a + mult a (b-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

What happens if `b` is `0`?

Comment: In short, how does it know when to stop?

Answer (score 2):

You could always try a more original, haskell-ish solution  =P

```
 mult a b = sum $ take b $ repeat a
```

Comment: What about `mult a b = sum [ a | i <- [1..b] ]` or even better `mult = (*)`

Comment: Well the question asks about recursion too

Comment: I'm sorry Dario, is there better for you?  =P
mult a b = iterate (+a) 0 !! b

Comment: Or even haskell-ish in eta-reduced form, without formal parameters :) - mult = (sum.).(.repeat).take

Comment: I'm sorry sir Matajon, but you are now BANNED from lambdabot.

Comment: `take b $ repeat a == replicate b a`

Comment: And then we just passed the line of effortless readability, although I'd assume a more experienced Data.List Haskeller than myself would understand "mult = sum . flip replicate" effortlessly.

Answer (score 1):

with any recursive function, there should be at least 2 cases.

a base case and a recursive case.

to make this more explicit, the use of the case (like the cases I mentioned above) statement is nice and easy to understand.

```
mult a b = case b of
    0 -> 0                -- the base case, multiply by 0 = 0
    _ -> a + mult a (b-1) -- recursive addition case (_ matches anything
                          -- but 0 is already covered)
```

Comment: To be exact, _ matches anything, but if b is 0 it's already matched so we'd never get to the _ case.